# Reshaping this array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, numba

Given this array X:

```
[1 2 3 2 3 1 4 5 7 1]
```

and the row length array R:

```
[3 2 5]
```

that represents the lengths of each row after the transformation.

I am looking for a computationally efficient function to reshape X into this array Y:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3. nan nan]
 [ 2.  3. nan nan nan]
 [ 1.  4.  5.  7.  1.]]
```

---

These are merely simplified version of the actual arrays I am working on. My actual arrays are more like this:

```
R = np.random.randint(5, size = 21000)+1
X = np.random.randint(10, size = np.sum(R))
```

I have already got down a function to generate the reshaped array, but the function runs way too slow. I have tried some Numba features to speed it up, but they generate to many error messages to handle. My super slow function:

```
def func1(given_array, row_length):

    corresponding_indices = np.cumsum(row_length)



    desired_result = np.full([len(row_length),np.amax(row_length)], np.nan)
    desired_result[0,:row_length[0]] = given_array[:corresponding_indices[0]]

    for i in range(1,len(row_length)):
        desired_result[i,:row_length[i]] = given_array[corresponding_indices[i-1]:corresponding_indices[i]]

    return desired_result
```

This function takes a daunting 34ms per loop when the sizes of the input_arrays haven't exceeded 100K yet. I am looking for a function that does the same thing with the same sizes but in under 10ms per loop

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def func2(given_array, row_length):
    given_array = np.asarray(given_array)
    row_length = np.asarray(row_length)
    mask = row_length[:,None] > np.arange(row_length.max())
    out = np.full(mask.shape, np.nan)
    out[mask] = given_array
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [305]: a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 1]
     ...: b = [3, 2, 5]

In [306]: func2(a,b)
Out[306]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., nan, nan],
       [ 2.,  3., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  4.,  5.,  7.,  1.]])
```

Timings and verification on large dataset -

```
In [323]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: R = np.random.randint(5, size = 21000)+1
     ...: X = np.random.randint(10, size = np.sum(R))

In [324]: %timeit func1(X,R)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop

In [325]: %timeit func2(X,R)
1000 loops, best of 3: 657 µs per loop

In [332]: o1 = func1(X,R)

In [333]: o2 = func2(X,R)

In [334]: np.allclose(np.where(np.isnan(o1),0,o1),np.where(np.isnan(o2),0,o2))
Out[334]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for you help @Divakar, however when I run compare the results together using np.array_equal(result1, result2), the output is false. Note that I am running this over my size = 60K arrays

Comment: @mathguy Output has NaNs. You can't use `np.array_equal` that treats NaNs as not equals. Added timing section that shows one way on how to compare results.